# canon advanced printing technology setup launcher has stopped working

Tags: laser-printer

my printer is canon LBP2900 and when I setup it to my computer (windows 7) it appears this statment:
canon advanced printing technology setup launcher has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the result of outdated drivers, you can follow the link below to install the latest drivers for your system:

[Canon i-SENSYS LBP2900 - Software & Drivers](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900.aspx)

Once installed, restart your system and try to setup again, the issue should be resolved.